# ksort function dont work in smarty PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, smarty, ksort

i am trying to ksort an array, it worked when i was working with php, but i tried this in smarty template it didnt worked..

i tried like this

```
{{ksort($var)}}
```

but it returned this bool value and it even prints it..

```
1
```

actual array in $var is

```
array(1) {   [1]=>   array(2) {     ["Name"]=>     NULL     ["SubMenu"]=>     array(1) {       [1]=>       array(1) {         ["SubName"]=>         NULL       }     }   } }
```

I have even tried `{{$var = ksort($var)}}` but it just store that bool value.
any ideas how to ksort this array in smarty??

Comment: I'm not familiar with smarty, but `ksort()` always returns a boolean - it manipulates the array it was given as input

Comment: but it used to sort an array which i further use in foreach loop..
how can it return boolean now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) `ksort()` always returns a boolean and the array is modified by reference.
You could assign the result of `ksort()` to a unused variable and use the array for your output like this.

```
{$tmp = ksort($var)}
{$var}
```

Comment: yup. i am using the sorted array variable and that stupid boolean is not printing in top cuz of assigning it to unused variable..
thanks..